# python select item from list

Tags: python, list

I have the following in a .txt file which are saved from a game. i need to rerun the game inserting the items where appropriate.

```
(' A', '1', '2', '+1.25', '+0', '4', (123,321))
(' B', '1', '2', '-0', '+0.25', 'V', (05,245))
(' 1', '0', '6', '+0', '-0.25', 'V', (10,250))
(' 2', '0', '6', '-0.5', '-1.75', '4', (190,8))
(' 3', '2', '4', '-1', '1', '3', (180,100))
```

the code used to recover the items is:-

```
Z=[None]*10
i=0
TT = 'TestZZ.txt'
with open (TT, 'r') as f:
    array=[]
    for line in f:
        Z[i] = line
        i = i+1
```

the recovered list for Z[1] is
"(' B', '1', '2', '-0', '+0.25', 'V', (05,245))\n"

i need to get each item either as a string of num
if I do Z[1][3] i get 'B' not -0 as expected

help please

Comment: TestZZ.txt is the name of the text file used

Comment: `"(' B', '1', '2', '-0', '+0.25', 'V', (05,245))\n"` is a complete string not a list separated with commas. This is the why you will get `Z[1][0] = "("` , `Z[1][1] = " ' "`, `Z[1][5] = ","` and so on .

Comment: I would suggest you to use `Pickle` module it would preserve your data type and you wont have to spend much time on extracting relevant information out of some text

Comment: could you please show me the code to pickle T[0]...T[5], the data, so that i can read them back

Answer (score 3):

A simpler and effective soluton could be

```
// Say Z[1] is "(' B', '1', '2', '-0', '+0.25', 'V', (05,245))\n"
import ast
print ast.literal_eval(Z[1]) 
// this should return (' B', '1', '2', '-0', '+0.25', 'V', (5, 245))
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: this helps bur I still can not easily get the values out as they are not the same length if I could load direct from .txt file to list ie. ['B', '1', '2', '-0', '+0.25', 'V', (05,245)] I can then recover the items

Comment: I do not know if this makes it easier. All the values returned are printed directly to a screen without any calculation except the tuple at the end which is a screen position

Comment: to change this to a list just do => data = list(ast.literal_eval(Z[1]))

Answer (score 1):

The contents of `Z[1]` is *string* `"(' B', '1', '2', '-0', '+0.25', 'V', (05,245))"`, not a list as you may expect... And:

```
Z[1][0] = '('
Z[1][1] = "'"
Z[1][2] = ' '
Z[1][3] = 'B'
```

So the result is correct, simplified parser for your data would be:

```
>>> data = "(' B', '1', '2', '-0', '+0.25', 'V', (05,245))"
>>> data.split(',')
["(' B'", " '1'", " '2'", " '-0'", " '+0.25'", " 'V'", ' (05', '245))']
>>> data.split(',')[2]
" '2'"
>>> data.split(',')[2].strip(', ')
"'2'"
>>> data.split(',')[2].strip("' ")
'2'
>>>
```

But it doesn't handle strings like `' B, A'` and so on... so you may want to write more robust parser. Alternatively you may use for example XML data format or use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/pickle.html).

Comment: can i convert the string to a list as i need the items  B  1  2 -0 +0.25 etc as they will be printed direct to screen it will not matter if they are a string or number

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using Pickle probably not the best but it seems to work.

```
import pickle
T=[None]*10
R=[None]*10
T[0]=('bs:','300:','test3.txt ','5:FR456')
T[1]=('Bisley', '400', '4', 'Fred', 'CD45')
T[2]=(' A', '1', '2', '+1.25', '+0', '4')
T[3]=(' B', '1', '2', '-0', '+0.25', 'V')
T[4]=(' 1', '0', '6', '+0', '-0.25', 'V')
T[5]=(' 2', '0', '6', '-0.5', '-1.75', '4')



output = open("save1.pkl", 'wb')
for i in range(0,10):


    pickle.dump(T[i], output)


output.close()

inputFile = open("save1.pkl", 'rb')
```

for i in range(0,10):
    R[i] = pickle.load(inputFile)

inputFile.close()
for i in range(0,10):
    print R[i]

Comment: Many thanks for the help & sugestions I now have a working solution